# Plotly AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_traces'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
colors = ['gold', 'mediumturquoise', 'darkorange', 'lightgreen']
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels= 
['ASIA','AFRICA','EUROPE','AMERICA'], 
values=[9000,20,12,5000])])
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo='label+percent', textinfo='value', 
textfont_size=20,
marker=dict(colors=colors, line=dict(color='#000000', width=2)))
fig.show()
```

I use plotly for making charts. I need to make a chart  from  above code  but it is giving error

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'update_traces'

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing can happen if multiple versions of Plotly are installed simultaneously such as via pip and via conda. If you try uninstalling with both methods and then reinstalling with one just one that should clear things up.

Comment: THANKS. But I have solved this by updating my plotly version.